# Apparent speed of an object in a circular orbit in Schwarzschild geometry

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, differential-geometry, orbital-motion

Does an object in a circular orbit around a massive body in Schwarzschild geometry seem to move faster for a stationary observer located close to the massive body, compared to how the same object moves for a stationary observer located far from the massive body? In other words, will close and far observers disagree about the orbital period of an object in a circular orbit?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an orbiting object is the prototypical clock. Like any clock it is subject to gravitational time dilation.

Comment: It probably needs clarification that an orbiting object is the prototypical clock located in a specific place, and although an observer may know that his local clock is behind (or ahead), to actually see this, he must simultaneously compare the readings of both his local clock and the prototypical clock. Two questions arise, where is this prototypical clock located and how does light propagate from it to the observer?